Private class member variable is `undefined` when calling a member function
Suppose the following class:
class MyClass {
    private keysPressed: string[] = [];

    configure() {
        window.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp);
    }

    handleKeyUp(e: KeyboardEvent) {
        this.keysPressed.push(e.key);
    }
}

The following throws an error:
const instance = new MyClass();
instance.configure(); // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

If I add console.log(this.keysPressed) in configure, it sees keysPressed as expected, however handleKeyUp seems to behave differently.
Why is this happening?

You must bind the correct this context to the handleKeyUp method since you are passing it as a callback: window.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp.bind(this));

handleKeyUp is no more associated with object, once you add it to an event handler. Arrow functions are made for this. change handleKeyUp to an arrow function
